# Регулярка c 3-я группами и подэлементами

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Всем привет,
Выложил небольщой кусочек html-кода 
c 3-я группами

```
Alternative
Anime
Arabic
```

и нужно регуляркой разобрать группы с подэлементами.
Эти группы имеют подэлементы завернутые в

Но не все : 2 элемент НЕ имеет подэлементов поэтому 
регулярка работает неправильно и во вторую группу Anime попадают элементы из 3й группы
[sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a412acd03a6514212882e62d555c88516ff55df6)
Понятно что в регулярку можно было бы добавить условие

```
list top-level-subgenres
```

но тогда 2я группа Anime будет пропущена - чего не хотелось бы.

Можно ли составить регурярку так чтобы попали все 3 группы с правильными подэлементами и 2я группа была пустой ?

Спасибо!

Comment: `Выложил небольщой кусочек html-кода c 3-я группами` это мало похоже на html, это просто три строки текста.

Comment: Там ссылка на http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/ с кодом

Answer (score 1):

[Не нужно парсить HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/735446). Воспользуйтесь [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) или другими [альтернативными](http://htmlparsing.com/php.html) средствами специально предназначенными для разбора HTML. Пример работы с DOMDocument:

```
# создаём парсер
$dom = new DOMDocument();

# Загружаем html строку
# @ перед вызовом заглушает ошибки т.к.
# loadHTML может кидать исключения при невалидном HTML
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

# получаем всем теги <a>
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) {
        # печатаем содержимое <a href>
        echo $link->getAttribute('href');
        echo "<br />";
}
```